# Finding the average transaction, per user in Excel. With two criteria to satisfy (user match and month match), each row is a transaction?

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum, match, countif

I am encountering something I am finding challanging to understand how to script and I was hoping maybe someone who has better excel knowledge may be able to help!

UserID is in column A, and DateofTransaction Is in column I, 
I have a code that identifies any change between user id or Month as a 1 else 0. :

ENTERED INTO COLUMN O

```
=IF(A2<>A1,1,IF(I2<>I1,1,0))
```

if the ids are Not the same then 1, if the ids are the same then it checks if the months are not the same then 1 too, if both are satisfied then a 0.

Then to try to create some logic where it can group each set I have written
 Column O is the

```
=IF(O2+O3=2,1,IF(O2=0,IF(O3=1,2,IF(O2+O3=0,Q1+1,null))))
```

Which just identifies the groups of months but unsuccessfully at the moment, What I am looking for is Blank cells if it is not the only one in the month for the user. **example excel below**

```
Column A  | Column I  |  Column O     |  Column Q  | Column R |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
user id   | date      |  0 or 1 match |  transactions per month| Transacting month count
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         | Mar-16    |  1            |  1       | 6
1         | Apr-16    |  1            |  BLANK   | 6
1         | Apr-16    |  0            |  2       | 6
1         | Aug-16    |  1            |  1       | 6
2         | Aug-16    |  1            |  BLANK   | 1
2         | Aug-16    |  0            |  BLANK   | 1
2         | Aug-16    |  0            |  BLANK   | 1 
2         | Aug-16    |  0            |  4       | 1
```

I will then need to do an Average transactions per month for each user over their lifetime individually. The transacting month count was created with a LookUp to calculate their relative month count.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
C

Comment: **`I have written Column O`**... I believe you meant Column Q and Not O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the formula that you can use for your question regarding formula in column Q:

```
=IF(O2+O3=2,1,IF(OR(AND(O2+O3=0,O3<>""),(AND(O2+O3=1,O2=1))),"",COUNTIFS(I:I,I2,A:A,A2)))
```

Put this in Cell Q2 and drag it down till you have data.

Comment: That is amazing. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help :)